# Runtime error when deserialiasing in Jackson - InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, json, azure, jackson, option-type

I'm currently working on a [bug fix for the azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/pull/14305) and when trying to deserialise some JSON into a class with an Optional, I am getting an InvlidDefinitionException. What am I doing wrong? I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the code doing the deserialisation:

```
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = JacksonObjectMapperFactory.getInstance();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        UserGroups groupsFromJson = objectMapper.readValue(responseInJson, UserGroups.class);
```

```
public final class JacksonObjectMapperFactory {

    private JacksonObjectMapperFactory() {
    }

    public static ObjectMapper getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static final ObjectMapper INSTANCE = new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Here is the mapped class being used for deserialisation:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserGroups {

    @JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")
    private Optional<String> odataNextLink;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private List<UserGroup> value;

    public UserGroups(Optional<String> odataNextLink, List<UserGroup> value) {
        this.odataNextLink = odataNextLink;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Optional<String> getOdataNextLink() {
        return odataNextLink;
    }

    public List<UserGroup> getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is the UserGroup class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9064197572478554735L;

    @JsonProperty("objectId")
    @JsonAlias("id")
    private String objectID;

    @JsonProperty("objectType")
    @JsonAlias("@odata.type")
    private String objectType;

    @JsonProperty("displayName")
    private String displayName;

    public UserGroup(String objectID, String objectType, String displayName) {
        this.objectID = objectID;
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public String getObjectID() {
        return objectID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof UserGroup)) {
            return false;
        }
        final UserGroup group = (UserGroup) o;
        return this.getDisplayName().equals(group.getDisplayName())
                && this.getObjectID().equals(group.getObjectID())
                && this.getObjectType().equals(group.getObjectType());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(objectID, objectType, displayName);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting when running the tests:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Cannot construct instance of `com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.UserGroups` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects","value":[{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"12345678-7baf-48ce-96f4-a2d60c26391e","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"this is group1","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"group1","lastDirSyncTime":"2017-08-02T12:54:37Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"something","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesDomainName":null,"onPremisesNetBiosName":null,"onPremisesSamAccountNam"[truncated 1554 chars]; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1615)
```

This is an example JSON I would like to deserialise:

```
{
   "odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects",
   "odata.nextLink":"directoryObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/userId/memberOf?$skiptoken=X'XXXXXXXX'",
   "value":[
      {
         "odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
         "objectType":"Group",
         "objectId":"12345678-7baf-48ce-96f4-a2d60c26391e",
         "deletionTimestamp":null,
         "description":"this is group1",
         "dirSyncEnabled":true,
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

I am not very experienced with Jackson, any help is much appreciated. Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `UserGroup.java` class to something like this:

```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9064197572478554735L;
    private String objectId;
    private String objectType;
    private String description;

    public UserGroup(String objectID, String objectType, String displayName) {
        this.objectId = objectID;
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.description = displayName;
    }

    public UserGroup(){

    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof UserGroup)) {
            return false;
        }
        final UserGroup group = (UserGroup) o;
        return this.getDescription().equals(group.getDescription())
                && this.getObjectId().equals(group.getObjectId())
                && this.getObjectType().equals(group.getObjectType());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(objectId, objectType, description);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserGroup{" +
                "objectID='" + objectId + '\'' +
                ", objectType='" + objectType + '\'' +
                ", displayName='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And `UserGroups.java` class also :

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserGroups {

    @JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")
    private Optional<String> odataNextLink;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private List<UserGroup> value;

    public UserGroups(Optional<String> odataNextLink, List<UserGroup> value) {
        this.odataNextLink = odataNextLink;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Optional<String> getOdataNextLink() {
        return odataNextLink;
    }

    public List<UserGroup> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public UserGroups(){

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserGroups{" +
                "odataNextLink=" + odataNextLink +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

After that, everything should work fine.

Comment: The fields in the response are different for v1 and v2 endpoints of the microsoft API so I wanted to avoid adding variables for every field. I annotated the UserGroup and UserGroups classes with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @phil in your `UserGroup.java` class you have two fields `objectID` and `description` which do not exist in JSON message. Therefore, if you don't annotate them with `@JsonProperty` annotation and provide the name of macthing filed from JSON message deserilization will fail. Also you need to have default empty constructor. I edited my answer. You can try it.

Comment: `UserGroup.java` contains the `objectId` field. I have also annotated them with @JsonProperty but that doesn't work either. Because of `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, I shouldn't need to add a variable for every field in the JSON. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes

Comment: Which version of Jackson you are using? In Jackson 2.x, the @JsonIgnoreProperties reside in com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation package, hence you need to import it as :
**import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties.**
If you are using an older version of Jackson API e.g. Jackson 1.x then this annotation belongs to a different package, beware of that, especially if you have both Jackson 1.x and Jackson 2.x in your classpath

Comment: I'm using jackson 2.11.2, I removed the imports to make the code snippet shorter, but I'll add them in again.